# Show that x, y, and z are in exponential sequence.

Tags: sequences-and-series

If log(x), log(y), and log(z) are consecutive terms of a linear sequence. Show that x, y, and z are in exponential sequence.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. That said, this is not a "solve my problem for me" site. If you [edit] the question to show us what you tried and where you are stuck we may be able to help. Use mathjax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Please see 
[this article on MathSE protocol](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236). As onerous as the article may appear to you, it provides a defense mechanism against the MathSE forum being used as a *do my homework* forum. In particular, please see the **Edit-Tools** section of the article, and the portion of the article that discusses *showing work*. It is **irrelevant** whether the problem is homework. What counts is whether the protocol is observed.

Answer (score 0):

If by linear sequence you mean that $\ln x, \ln y,\ln z$ are each a multiple of the other by a constant, say $r$, we can assume that $$\ln z=r\ln y\\ \ln y=r \ln x$$

and thus $$\ln z=r^2 \ln x$$

For $x,y,z$ to be in an exponential sequence, each will have to differ from the preceding one by being raised to a constant power.

But by the definition of the logarithm we have $$\large x= e^{\ln x}\\\large y=e^{\ln y}=e^{\ln x^r}=x^r\\\large z= e^{\ln z}=e^{r\ln y}=e^{\ln (x^r)^r}=(x^r)^r$$

So indeed, $x,y,z$ differ by the exponent $r$.